# dynamic table creation and its mapping with pojo in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a web application. We are using Hibernate as ORM in our project. Actually, our application creates some tables dynamically based on user selection.For Example,if the user creates a form by name Student,and adds its attributes like name,roll no,subject,class etc.. then on runtime,there should be a table created by name student with columns name,roll no,subject,class and also its related class and its hibernate mapping file. Is there any way of doing so?

Thanks in advance,
Mahalaxmi

Comment: Its duplication question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192031/dynamically-create-table-and-java-classes-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

store hibernate mapping xml externally and edit a `<dynamic-component>` section in that

### Option 2

use a fixed `Map<string, string>` or `Map<string, object>` property and mapping